# MySQL proportionate subset of returned rows

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a query like so

```
SELECT
    t.trial,
    count(*),
    MAX(d.value)
FROM data d
INNER JOIN trial_info t 
    ON d.instance_timestamp BETWEEN t.trial_start_timestamp AND t.trial_end_timestamp
GROUP BY t.trial;
```

which returns

```
t.trial | count(*) | MAX(d.value)
---------------------------------
1       | 80       | 176
2       | 63       | 219
3       | 49       | 109
4       | 67       | 155
```

One row of `d` represents one second, so condensing on `t.trial` means that `count(*)` will return the number of seconds in each trial, and `MAX(d.value)` will be the largest value observed in those seconds.

**Question**: How can I whittle the results to only return the middle 50% of each trial *and the MAX value in that time*? I want to throw out the first 25% of the trial time as well as the last 25%. My subquery skills aren't so hot...

Here is my idea so far. Substituting this join works when `computedValue` is set to a static number. However I want `computedValue` to be a percentage of the rows returned (displayed in the `count(*)` result column above).

```
INNER JOIN trial_info t ON d.instance_timestamp BETWEEN
    DATE_ADD(t.trial_start_timestamp, INTERVAL computedValue SECOND) AND
    DATE_SUB(t.trial_end_timestamp, INTERVAL computedValue SECOND)
```

Comment: Please provide sample results.  Your query returns a count.  So the middle 50% would be `0.5*count(*)`.

Comment: Sample results now included.

Comment: Can you provide samples of the data?  It still doesn't make sense.  If you are calculating the max of a column in `t`, what relationship does this have to `data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` to get the 0.25*interval in second from `t.trial_start_timestamp` to `t.trial_end_timestamp` and round it to integer using `FLOOR`:

```
FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.trial_start_timestamp,t.trial_end_timestamp)*0.25)
```

So the join condition is:

```
INNER JOIN trial_info t ON d.instance_timestamp BETWEEN
    DATE_ADD(t.trial_start_timestamp, INTERVAL FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.trial_start_timestamp,t.trial_end_timestamp)*0.25) SECOND) AND
    DATE_SUB(t.trial_end_timestamp, INTERVAL FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.trial_start_timestamp,t.trial_end_timestamp)*0.25) SECOND)
```

EDIT:

If your 50% is based on number of trials, not timestamp, the solution will be to use LIMIT and OFFSET in a subquery to get the boundary from 25% to 75% number of trial for d.instance_timestamp:

```
d.instance_timestamp BETWEEN (SELECT d1.instance_timestamp FROM data d1
where d1.instance_timestamp BETWEEN t.trial_start_timestamp AND t.trial_end_timestamp ORDER BY d1.instance_timestamp ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET (SELECT FLOOR(0.25 * COUNT(*)) FROM data d2 where d2.instance_timestamp BETWEEN t.trial_start_timestamp AND t.trial_end_timestamp)) 
AND 
(SELECT d3.instance_timestamp FROM data d3
where d3.instance_timestamp BETWEEN t.trial_start_timestamp AND t.trial_end_timestamp ORDER BY d3.instance_timestamp ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET (SELECT FLOOR(0.75 * COUNT(*)) FROM data d4 where d4.instance_timestamp BETWEEN t.trial_start_timestamp AND t.trial_end_timestamp))
```

However, MySQL does not support subquery as value for LIMIT and OFFSET. To do this in MySQL, you will need to compute the instance_timestamp at the 25th and 75th percentiles using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
    d.instance_timestamp BETWEEN 
    (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(d1.instance_timestamp ORDER BY d1.instance_timestamp SEPARATOR ','), ',' , 0.25 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1) FROM  data d1
where d1.instance_timestamp BETWEEN t.trial_start_timestamp AND t.trial_end_timestamp) 
    AND 
    (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(d2.instance_timestamp ORDER BY d2.instance_timestamp SEPARATOR ','), ',' , 0.75 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1) FROM  data d2
where d2.instance_timestamp BETWEEN t.trial_start_timestamp AND t.trial_end_timestamp)
```

Comment: @user3477312 . . . But by your description of the problem, arithmetic on the timestamps should work.

Comment: Wow, thank you. You guys are right. I finally see it. I was really over-complicating this. Though I am still wondering how to do it the way I described... :)

Comment: @anhlc Subquery for OFFSET in MySQL...?

Comment: @user3477312, oops I forget about no subquery support for LIMIT and OFFSET in MySQL. You will need to compute the 25th/75th percentile timestamp in this case. Update my answer now.